# Recursive set that many-to-one reduces to a non recursive set

Tags: logic, computability

It is a known theorem that if B is a recursive set and A many-to-one reduces to B, then A is also a recursive set.

I am looking for a counterexample for the converse, so a non-recursive set B such that a recursive set A many-to-one reduces to it.

I have already proved that B must be recursively enumerable.

Comment: B doesn't have to be r.e., it can be any set that's not $\emptyset$ and not $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @DonThousand But $\psi$ isn't a reduction — it might map some $i \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \psi(B)$ into $\psi(B)$. This will be the case unless $B$ is a union of mod-$n$ cosets, in which case $B$ is recursive. 

It's not clear what your point is. It seems like you're starting to claim that every non-recursive set is many-one reducible to a finite set.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be any non-empty proper subset of $\mathbb N$ and let $p \in B, q \in \mathbb N \setminus B$ be arbitrary but fixed. Let $A$ be a recursive subset of $\mathbb N$ and define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} p &\text{if }\  x \in A \\ q &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is recursive and $x \in A \iff f(x) \in B$, i.e. $A$ is many-to-one reducible to $B$.